# How to execute on update query with where clause by calling hibernate template

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

here is my update query

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("update CloudSvrUsersSecQuestion c   set c.secQuesAnswer="); 
// it will call five times for 5 db recod the below query
for(CloudSvrUsersSecQuestion lisq:user.getListSecQuestion()) {
    queryString.append("' ").append(lisq.getSecQuesAnswer()).append("' ").append("where c.secQuesId=").append(lisq.getSecQuesId());
}

// how to execute this query for updating in db below is my approach but its not correct
CloudSvrUsersSecQuestion my pojo class mapped with db

secQuesList = (List<CloudSvrUsersSecQuestion>)super.getHibernateTemplate().update(queryString.toString());
```

please help me how to write execute this query

Comment: see my answer and check if it helps to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [bulkUpdate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#bulkUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) method of Hibernate Template.

Also refer to this link for similar question - How to use HibernateTemplate and HQL update query ?[enter link description here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/27727-how-to-use-hibernatetemplate-and-hql-update-query)